# DLL importation

Tags: c#, dll

I have to do a soft (using C#.NET) able to flash 2 microcontroller (CPU/PIC).
To do it i have a VB6 DLL, unfortunately i can't use it easily in VS.
I found a development kit wrotte in CPP

this kit contain:

- a file Flasher.lib -> can't see the source code
- // Flasher.exp -> can't see the source code
- // DLL_interface.bas

sample  DLL_interface.bad :

```
Option Explicit

'dll function declarations

Declare Function SetCom Lib "st10flasher.dll" (ByVal PortName$, ByVal comspeed As Long) As Long

Declare Function LoadFile Lib "st10flasher.dll" (ByVal FileName$, ByRef Fsize As Long) As Long

Declare Function InitMonitor Lib "st10flasher.dll" (ByVal device As Any) As Long

Declare Function ProgramFlash Lib "st10flasher.dll" () As Long

Declare Function GetError Lib "st10flasher.dll" (ByVal BufferForStatus As Any) As Long
```

- // basicinterface.h

sample BasicInterface.h

```
#ifndef _BASIC_INTERFACE_H
#define _BASIC_INTERFACE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" 
{
#endif

#ifndef ST10FLASHER_API
#define ST10FLASHER_API __declspec(dllimport) // To import flasher function
#endif

// Communication function
ST10FLASHER_API unsigned int PASCAL SetCom(char *PortName, unsigned int ComSpeed);
ST10FLASHER_API unsigned int PASCAL CloseCom(void);
ST10FLASHER_API unsigned int PASCAL ComIsKline(void);
ST10FLASHER_API unsigned int PASCAL SetComSpeed(char *portName, unsigned int ComSpeed);
ST10FLASHER_API unsigned int PASCAL CalibrateSpeed(char *PortName, unsigned int ComSpeed);
ST10FLASHER_API unsigned int PASCAL IsAvailableBaudRate(const double frequency,const unsigned int     baudrate);
```

i have no idea how to use it. If someone have an idea please :) !
Thank's a lot !

Comment: `unfortunately i can't use it easily in VS` What are those difficulties you experiencing?

Comment: When i import a reference into VS, i have an error : check if the file if an assembly or a valid COM component.

Comment: have you registered it?

Comment: I tried, but i can't,

REGSVR32 mydll.dll isn't working
i tried that way to :%systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32 st10flasher.dll

Comment: `Isn't working` tells a lot. Please be more specific and write all details.

Comment: Yes sorry, the "exact" sentence (i have to translate ) "DLLregisterServer" can't be found , check if "DLL" is a valid DLL file or OCX then retry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't reference the DLL using 'Add Reference'. Instead, just place the DLL next to the C# EXE you're using. You already have an example of how to do this in VB.NET, you just need to translate this code into C#:

You will need to put this in your C# code:

```
  [DllImport(@"st10flasher.dll")]
  public static extern long SetCom(string portName, long int comspeed);
```

Then you can simply call it like a C# method. e.g.:

```
  long x = SetCom("MyPort", 1600);
```

For more help, Google for 'Platform Invoke' (also called P/Invoke).

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to reference the st10flasher.dll 
put it in system32 folder or Bin folder in your application

And you won't use the original dll, you will use the class that interface it ,

```
class whatever
    <DllImport("st10flasher.dll", CharSet := CharSet.Unicode)> _
     Public Shared Function SetCom(port as string, comspeed as int16 ) as integer

End Class
```

in main form ( for example )

```
dim result as int16 = whatever.SetCom("808080", 55)
```

Comment: thanks for answer, once i added it in system32 or Bin how should i use it ?

Comment: No, don't put it in system32

Comment: you wont use the original dll, you will use the class that interface it , 
class whatever