# Crash C# Application using Marshalling

Tags: c#, c++, dll, marshalling, vhosts

I created a C# application which use 2 C++ Dll, the first one work very well, but i have some trouble with the second.

I'm flashing a CPU :

My dll :

```
    [DllImport(@"st10flasher.dll")]
    public static extern long SetCom(string PortName, long comspeed);

    [DllImport(@"st10flasher.dll")]
    public static extern long LoadFile(string FileName, ref long Fsize);

    [DllImport(@"st10flasher.dll")]
    public static extern long InitMonitor(string device);

    [DllImport(@"st10flasher.dll")]
    public static extern long ProgramFlash();

    [DllImport(@"st10flasher.dll")]
    public static extern long EraseFlash(long Block);

    [DllImport(@"st10flasher.dll")]
    public static extern long CloseCom();

    [DllImport(@"st10flasher.dll")]
    public static extern long BlockNBToErase(bool EraseBlockError);
```

It usually work but sometime it crash with.
    -I checked the event log and found the exception code :  0xc0000409
    -It ask me if i want to debug it with VS then i have this stack :

[image]

The Error message isn't in english i'll try to translate :
 unmanaged exception 0x71E2CF1B (clr.dll). the instrumentation code stack cookie detected exceeding the stack buffer

What could it be ? thanks !

As you asked i added the VB declaration :

```
Declare Function SetCom Lib "st10flasher.dll" (ByVal PortName$, ByVal comspeed As Long) As Long
Declare Function LoadFile Lib "st10flasher.dll" (ByVal FileName$, ByRef Fsize As Long) As Long
Declare Function InitMonitor Lib "st10flasher.dll" (ByVal device As Any) As Long
Declare Function ProgramFlash Lib "st10flasher.dll" () As Long
Declare Function GetError Lib "st10flasher.dll" (ByVal BufferForStatus As Any) As Long
Declare Function EraseFlash Lib "st10flasher.dll" (ByVal Block As Long) As Long
Declare Function CloseCom Lib "st10flasher.dll" () As Long
```

/************************************************** EDIT **************************************************/

So i updated my functions declaration like that :

```
    [DllImport(@"st10flasher.dll")]
    public static extern uint SetCom([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string PortName, uint comspeed);

    [DllImport(@"st10flasher.dll")]
    public static extern uint LoadFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string FileName, ref uint Fsize);

    [DllImport(@"st10flasher.dll")]
    public static extern uint InitMonitor([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string device);

    [DllImport(@"st10flasher.dll")]
    public static extern uint ProgramFlash();

    [DllImport(@"st10flasher.dll")]
    public static extern uint EraseFlash(uint Block);

    [DllImport(@"st10flasher.dll")]
    public static extern uint CloseCom();

    [DllImport(@"st10flasher.dll")]
    public static extern uint BlockNBToErase(bool EraseBlockError);
```

and i found the dll's documentation :

```
unsigned int SetCom(char *PortName, unsigned int ComSpeed)
unsigned int CloseCom(void)
unsigned int LoadFile(char *filename)
unsigned int InitMonitor(char *target)
unsigned int EraseFlash(unsigned int BlockMask)
unsigned int ProgramFlash(void)
```

i tried to update my prototype using this post : [post StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450731/equivalent-char-in-c-sharp) But i still have the same error. Did i misunderstood something from the link ?

/******************************SOLVED****************************/

I solved my problem by creating an other C++ DLL which load and unload the st10flasher.dll

Comment: Everything... For example, you aren't using `CallingConvention.Cdecl`... Are your pinvoke methods `Stdcl`? Are all the parameters and return values correct? Without a .h file, how can we tell?

Comment: And note that rarely I've seen `long` used in a C library... In C for Windows, `sizeof(long) == sizeof(int)`, so unless in C it was a `long long int` ora `int64_t`, then you should use `int`

Comment: We need to see both sides.  You only showed us the C# code -- show us the C++ declarations.

Comment: Exception 0xc0000409 is very, very nasty.  The stack trace shows that it occurs while the garbage collector is running.  That's a very strong hint that the GC heap is corrupted.  Heap corruption is generally caused by bad pinvoke.  You clearly have a strong candidate here.  No slamdunk in the methods you showed, but *long* is very unlikely to be correct.  A *long* in C or C++ code is an *int* in .NET.

Comment: The error occurs with the ProgramFlash() method , and i use it like that :              long result = com.Dll_CPU_interface.ProgramFlash();
I think parameters are ok, the strangest thing it that i can work 10 time without crash .
I didn't know CallingConvention.Cdecl, should i use it to clear the buffer ? i don't have access to the dll's sources

Comment: Ok for the long, it seem legit . but i don't care about the returned values ( except for error handling ) for the moment.Does the returned value could  generate an error ? even if i don't use it ?

Comment: @PyNico Try enabling this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff361650%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (there is an example at the end)

Comment: @PyNico The parameters and return value must be **perfect** in size for a pinvoke, otherwise **bad things** happens.

Comment: @PyNico `I *think* parameters are ok`  Which is why you should show how your C++ functions are declared.  If the calling convention, return type, and parameter types are off, your functions will not work correctly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the problem is that i don't have the C++ functions , i just have a VB code which use the this DLL

Comment: @PyNico Then you need to show the VB code.  Also, you don't need the functions, just the C++ (or C) declaration and/or prototypes.  Else, how can you call functions blindly without knowing what the prototypes are?

Comment: @xanatos i added the NetFx40_PInvokeStackResilience , i'll check if the program still crash. I'll also check to change long to int64 if it doesn't work

Comment: @PyNico The NetFx40_PInvokeStackResilience  won't stop your program from crashing, but if it is crashing for the bad parameters/return types, sometimes it will crash telling it to you :-) (throwing an "unbalanced stack exception")

Comment: @PyNico This one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27168248/dll-importation from you... The names are nearly the same. We need the rows from the `basicinterface.h`

Comment: @xanatos i don't have this file anymore :(

Comment: @PyNico I will say that the vb file was badly written. Replace all the `long` with `uint`. The calling convention is Stdcall, so you don't have to set it.

Comment: These are VB6 declarations, they are not compatible with .NET.  A Long is an *int*, it is always a wild guess what Any might be.  But highly likely that is the one that corrupts the heap.  All you can do is guess at byte[] and pass a very large array to minimize the odds for corruption.

Comment: Thanks, i did it and it still flash i'll run my test tonight to know if it still bug. As you told me  it's StdCall , so i guess i don't need to write anything for it , this is the default convention  isn't it ?

Comment: @xanatos
I found the C++ prototype but it seem to i misunderstood something, i have updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[DllImport(@"st10flasher.dll")]
public static extern uint LoadFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string FileName, ref uint Fsize);
```

seems wrong:

```
unsigned int LoadFile(char *filename)
```

remove the `ref uint Fsize`

You didn't have a signature for this:

```
[DllImport(@"st10flasher.dll")]
public static extern uint BlockNBToErase(bool EraseBlockError);
```

Everything else should be correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i'll remove it... Should i add all function even if i don't use some ?

Comment: @PyNico What you don't use won't crash your program :-) No, you should have only the PInvokes that you use